# linux cron job to create file using python

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

bash script,

```
#! /bin/bash

echo 'hi bash'

aa
python ~/fledgling/cron/test.py

echo 'after python script'
```

here `aa` is alias, which activates virtualenv

```
alias aa='cd /home/fledgling/projects/myblog/base'
```

python script,

```
import time

with open('~/fledgling/cron/%s.txt' % time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d__%H:%M:%S"), 'w') as f:
    f.write('%s' % time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d__%H:%M:%S"))
```

I want to to run this python script for every one minute.

crontab,

```
* * * * * ~/fledgling/cron/test.sh >> ~/fledgling/cron/log.txt
```

contents of ~/fledgling/cron/log.txt ,

```
hi bash
after python script
```

Output of /var/log/syslog

```
 ✘ ✝ ~/fledgling/cron  tail -f /var/log/syslog  
Jun 24 13:46:01 mysys CRON[14697]: (mysys) CMD (~/fledgling/cron/test.sh >> ~/fledgling/cron/log.txt)
Jun 24 13:46:01 mysys CRON[14696]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 24 13:47:01 mysys CRON[14736]: (mysys) CMD (~/fledgling/cron/test.sh >> ~/fledgling/cron/log.txt)
Jun 24 13:47:01 mysys CRON[14735]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 24 13:48:01 mysys CRON[14747]: (mysys) CMD (~/fledgling/cron/test.sh >> ~/fledgling/cron/log.txt)
Jun 24 13:48:01 mysys CRON[14746]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 24 13:48:11 mysys crontab[14769]: (mysys) BEGIN EDIT (mysys)
Jun 24 13:48:59 mysys crontab[14769]: (mysys) END EDIT (mysys)
Jun 24 13:49:01 mysys CRON[14794]: (mysys) CMD (~/fledgling/cron/test.sh >> ~/fledgling/cron/log.txt)
Jun 24 13:49:01 mysys CRON[14793]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Permissions,

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysys mysys  476 Jun 24 13:57 log.txt
-rwxrw-r--  1 mysys mysys  153 Jun 24 13:37 test.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mysys mysys   91 Jun 24 13:32 test.sh
```

What I want ? I want to create text file every minute.

What is my problem ? I can see in log that after every minute bash script is running with no error, then why python script is not getting executed or not creating any text file ?

Comment: `#! /bin/bash` should be no space. `~` Where do you think that is going?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can not use `~` in python, [which will be expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) in shell not python.

Since mentioned by some answers, one thing to declared is

> A space after #! is optional.

I saw this from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), and I have checked that on my Mac, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

- No ~ in Python
- No space after ! in bash header
- Not sure bash launched by cron will guess your alias
- Not sure crontab accept ~
- Look at your log (/var/log/syslog maybe)
- Try redirect 2>/tmp/debug.log in crontab
- check if test.sh is executable

Answer (score 0):

If You are running that script on server then You may not be using:

```
os.path.expanduser('~')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your shell script use the full path rather then an alias.

aa=/home/fledgling/projects/myblog/base

cd $aa